# Visual Basic: Newbie questions

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am starting to learn visual basic. So far, it is quite simple and easy to use. I am liking it!

Anyway, I want to make applications a little bit more complex. So far I have done very silly things. I would appreciate if you could help me with these:

1. How do I open a new window (form)? Maybe I click a button on my main form and another form pops up. How do I "deactivate" the main form while the new form is running? (if I try to click the main form, an error sound plays)
2. So my second form has a text field and a "OK" button. If I click it, the second form closes activating the main form again. I want to "pass" the text in the text field from the second form to the first one. How do I do that?

Thank you, I am enjoying this new programming environment (didn't use Visual Studio much before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you on the right track assuming you are using vb.net and winforms.

The reason the error sound is playing when you click on the parent form is because the second form is opened as a application model form which prevents the application from removing focus from the second form while it is visible.

```
Public Class Form1

        Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Dim newForm As New Form2
            newForm.ShowDialog(Me)
            TextBox1.Text = newForm.GetInfo
            newForm.Dispose()
            newForm = Nothing
        End Sub
End Class


Public Class Form2

    Public ReadOnly Property GetInfo As String
        Get
            Return TextBox1.Text
        End Get
    End Property
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Say your second form id is frmOptions.  You can call frmOptions.Show() from the button click handler.
2. Expose a public property in the second form, i.e. public string ChoosenAnswer { get; set; }, before you close the form, assign the value to that public property or if you want to access the actual form control itself, you should still be able to, as long as its set as public.  From the main form you can just do myChoice = frmOptions.ChoosenAnswer

Answer (score 1):

1. In the taskbar you should see the word "project" click on it should say "Add Windows Form...”. Then a new window will appear, click on "Windows Form" then click Add in the bottom right of the window, you now have another form.

Answer (score -1):

What vb are you using? I understand your questions, but I will give you some sample code and the easy steps how to make it work.

1. Open 2 forms <to change the name of the form, go to name and set the form 1 to `frmMainform`  and set the form 2 to `frmSecondform`. You can see it in property window>
2. Then put command button and label in each form.
3. It's up to you if you will name it.
4. Go to `mainform` then double click the button `ok`.
   Code it

   ```
   frmMainshow.hide
   frmSecondform.show
   ```
5. Go to then second form then type this

   ```
   frmsecondform.hide
   frmmainform.show
   frmmainform.label1.text = "Pass"
   ```